# ffmpeg does not recognize any audio filters

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, noise, speech-recognition

I am trying to reduce noise from the audio files I extracted from videos. The objective is to recognize speech, so I was trying to filter out the frequencies above 300 and below 3000hz. I tried to use equalizer filter by issuing command:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i "amovie=input.wav,equalizer=f=1300:width_type=h:width=1000" output.wav
```

but it gives me error:

```
C:\Users\Sudh\Downloads>ffmpeg -f lavfi -i "amovie=input.wav,equalizer=f=300:w
th_type=h:width=3000" output.wav >output.txt
ffmpeg version git-2012-03-03-663d727-xuggle-4.0 Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the F
peg developers
  built on Mar 20 2012 16:24:58 with gcc 4.5.2
  configuration: --prefix=/d/desarrollo/xuggle --extra-version=xuggle-4.0 --ex
a-cflags=-I/d/desarrollo/xuggle/xuggle_v5/xuggle-xuggler-win/build/native/x86_
-w64-mingw32/captive/stage/d/desarrollo/xuggle/include --extra-ldflags=-L/d/de
rrollo/xuggle/xuggle_v5/xuggle-xuggler-win/build/native/x86_64-w64-mingw32/cap
ve/stage/d/desarrollo/xuggle/lib --enable-shared --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree
-enable-libx264 --enable-version3 --enable-cross-compile --cross-prefix= --arc
x86_64 --target-os=mingw32 --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvorbis --enable-lib
eora --enable-libspeex --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enab
-libopencore-amrwb --enable-librtmp --enable-openssl --enable-zlib --enable-li
px
  libavutil      51. 41.100 / 51. 41.100
  libavcodec     54.  4.100 / 54.  4.100
  libavformat    54.  1.100 / 54.  1.100
  libavdevice    53.  4.100 / 53.  4.100
  libavfilter     2. 62.101 /  2. 62.101
  libswscale      2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libswresample   0.  7.100 /  0.  7.100
  libpostproc    52.  0.100 / 52.  0.100
[wav @ 00000000006DB360] max_analyze_duration 5000000 reached at 5120000
[amovie @ 00000000006D9DF0] seek_point:0 format_name:(null) file_name:input.wa
stream_index:0
[lavfi @ 00000000006D97F0] No such filter: 'equalizer'
amovie=input.wav,equalizer=f=300:width_type=h:width=3000: Invalid argument
```

I tried to use bandreject filter too

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i "amovie=input.wav,equalizer=f=1300:width_type=h:width=1000" output.wav
```

but with the same result saying "No such filter bandreject".

What am I missing? Is there a better way to reduce noise using ffmpeg?

Also I am using latest 64 bit static version from http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/

Comment: You should provide the complete `ffmpeg` console output as text instead of an image. It is easier to read, searchable, and does not depend on third-party hosts. Your `ffmpeg` is probably too old, but it would be easier to find out if you provided the complete console output.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I changed the image, also I am using the latest build from zeranoe.com builds, however when I check filters using ffmpeg -filters I noticed that equalizer and bandreject do not appear in the list. How do I install those filters for my ffmpeg installation?

Comment: Hi, your ffmpeg version was built in 2012 -- the zeranoe site you linked to has builds from 2014 (**today**, in fact, as of this writing!). Is there any reason you are using such an old build when a much more recent one is available? It may not solve your problem, but there is very little reason to use an old ffmpeg since it is constantly evolving and improving.

Comment: @allquixotic: I downloaded the latest build and unzipped that.. I am not sure why is it showing 2012.. I repeated the process after your comment once again..and restarted the PC but it's still same

Comment: You appear to be unzipping your ffmpeg into a different folder, or running the wrong file. It could also be picking up dynamically linked libraries in your downloads folder from old versions of ffmpeg. My advice: re-download the very latest build of ffmpeg from zeranoe, then unzip the file into a *new folder*. then try running that. do not copy or move the new ffmpeg.exe into the downloads folder. what version does it display now?

Comment: You are correct.. I deleted the files in my c: ffmpeg and replaced them with the new ones but I am still getting getting the older version... interestingly i fI run the downloaded file directly it gives me correct version

Comment: Do you have an `ffmpeg` on your `%PATH%` environment variable, maybe?

Comment: Since you found a solution you can provide and accept your own answer to your question in case others have the same problem (and also so other potential answerers know that a solution was found).

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, which was simply migrating to the new version of ffmpeg from http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/ . Also make sure to restart the system and change environment variables to remove traces of older ffmpeg.